# postgresql exception catching or error handling in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

In below code i have created sample table  and written store procedure for exception handling ,the problem is if i insert integer values into columns name and email it is executing .if i pass integer values for name and email columns  it should throw exception saying that your passing data types is wrong for name and email columns.

Can any one help me.

```
CREATE TABLE people
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  name text,
  email text,
  CONSTRAINT people_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test() RETURNS integer AS'
BEGIN

BEGIN

INSERT INTO people(id,name,email) values(1,5,6);
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN RETURN -1;
END;

RETURN 1;

END'LANGUAGE plpgsql;


select * from test()


select * from people
```

Comment: `BEGIN ... EXCEPTION` block? What have you tried already? What searching/reading have you already done? Stack Overflow isn't a "write my code for me" site.

Comment: I have tried this below code i am able to print 1 when insert happen in the same if any synatax error in insert satatement i should print -1 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test() RETURNS VARCHAR AS'
BEGIN
BEGIN
INSERT INTO people(id,name,email) values(5,''h'',''l'');
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
END;
RETURN ''1'';
END'LANGUAGE plpgsql;

Comment: Well ... think about when you want to return `-1`. Maybe you should add a `RETURN -1` somewhere...

Answer (score 1):

This is the normal behavior, and it's not related to exception or error handling.

Assigning a numeric value to a text field in an SQL query works seamlessly, because PostgreSQL applies an **implicit cast** to the numeric literal (this also works with just about any datatype, since they all have a text representation through their I/O conversion routine).

This is tangentially mentioned in the doc for [CREATE CAST](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createcast.html):

> It is normally not necessary to create casts between user-defined
>   types and the standard string types (text, varchar, and char(n), as
>   well as user-defined types that are defined to be in the string
>   category). PostgreSQL provides automatic I/O conversion casts for
>   that. The automatic casts to string types are treated as assignment
>   casts, while the automatic casts from string types are explicit-only.